# can't handle multiple request using rabbitmq and masstransist in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am currently working with micro service architecture and .net core.
Rabbit MQ + MassTransit are being used to send and receive data between the micro services.
I have a host application in IIS and from 2 separate browsers I send the same request to micro service and that microservice calls other service using RabbitMQ.
I expect to get 2 separate requests hitting the consumer but instead get an   internal server error.

Startup:

```
services.AddScoped<OrderCompletedEventConsumer>();
            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.AddConsumer<Controllers.OrderController>();
            });

            services.AddSingleton(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("http://192.168.101.111:5672"),
                    "/", h =>
                    {
                        h.Username("Test");
                        h.Password("test");
                    });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "TestQUE", e =>
                {
                    e.Consumer<Controllers.OrderController>(provider);
                });
            }));

            //Register Publish Endpoint of RabbitMQ bus service
            services.AddSingleton<IPublishEndpoint>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());
            //Register Send Endpoint of RabbitMQ bus service
            services.AddSingleton<ISendEndpointProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());
            //Register Bus control for RabbitMQ
            services.AddSingleton<IBus>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<IBusControl>());
            //Regster Bus Service hosting
            services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BusService>();
```

Request From One microservice:-

```
IRequestClient<IAddRequest<IOrder>, IAddResponse<IOrder>> orderClient =
               new MessageRequestClient<IAddRequest<IOrder>, IAddResponse<IOrder>>(_bus,
                   EndpointAddress("orderQue"), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Convert.ToDouble("150")));
            var addResponse = orderClient.Request(new
            {
                entity = order
            });
            await Task.WhenAll(addResponse);
```

Consumer

```
public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IGetRequest<IOrder>> context)
        {
            // Operation and return result
            await context.RespondAsync<IGetResposne<IOffice>>(new
            {
                // send result.
            });
        }
```

In the consumer the 2 separate requests from different browser arrive but both are unsuccessful. However if I do one request at a time then it will work, why is this?

Please give any idea, suggestion or hint.

Thank you,

Comment: You don't start the bus. The bus must be started in order for consumers and request/response to work.

Comment: i am not getting can you please give some link or more details

Comment: Have you checked the error queue in RabbitMQ? This may give you some clues - if you have the RabbitMQ management pugin installed then open a browser to http://192.168.101.111:15672/ to see your queues and any dead messages.

Comment: @VinitPatel you are creating the instance of `IBusControl` but you never start the bus by calling `busControl.Start()` or `busControl.StartAsync()`

If you check the code here http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/configuration.html#aspnet-core, you will see that the bus is started in the `IHostedService` implementation but you can also start it as soon as you create it.

Comment: I have checked with provided document link and noted that services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BusService>(); using this it will always start with application start.

Comment: I see, I should have read the question more carefully. You say that only parallel requests fail. But you need to explain what exception you are getting.

Comment: Use a try/catch in your consume method - otherwise MassTransit will swallow any exceptions inside the middleware as mentioned here -  http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/exceptions.html This is also why i'm also encouraging you to look at the errors queues